# Css wont hide things on smaller screens

Tags: html, css

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway');


.navibar{
  background: rgba(20, 21, 22, .10);
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
  box-shadow: -1px 2px 5px black;
  width: 100%;

}

.nav-toggle {
  display: none;
}

.nav-toggle-label{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin-left: 1em;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.nav-toggle-label span,
.nav-toggle-label span::before,
.nav-toggle-label span::after {
    display: block;
    background: white;
    height: 2px;
    width: 2em;
    border-radius: 2px;
    position: relative;
}

.nav-toggle-label span::before,
.nav-toggle-label span::after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
}

.nav-toggle-label span::before{
  bottom: 7px;
}
.nav-toggle-label span::after{
  top: 7px;
}

nav{
    position: absolute;
    text-align: left;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(20, 21, 22, .4);
    width: 100%;
    transform: scale(1, 0);
    transform-origin: top;
    transition: transform 400ms ease-in-out;
}

nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

nav li {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  margin-left: 1em;
}

nav a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 150ms ease-in-out;
  user-select: none;
}

nav a:hover {
  color: #000;
}

.nav-toggle:checked ~ nav {
   transform: scale(1,1);
}

.nav-toggle:checked ~ nav a {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 250ms ease-in-out 250ms;
}
.center{
  color: white;
 position: absolute;
 padding: -101px 0;
 border: 1px solid black;
 box-shadow: -1px 1px 100px black;
 -webkit-text-stroke: 2px black;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 70px;
 width: 30%;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 margin-right: -50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  /*This should hide center when using mobile but for some reason it doesn't work am i doing something wrong?*/
  .center {
    display: none;
  }
  .nav-toggle-label{
    display: none;
  }

  .navibar{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr auto minmax(600px, 3fr) 1fr;
  }
  .logo{
    grid-column: 2 / 3;
  }

  nav{
    all: unset;
    grid-column: 3 / 4;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: center;
  }

  nav ul {
    display: flex;
  }

  nav li {
    margin-left: 3em;
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
  nav a {
    opacity: 1;
    position: relative;
  }
  nav a::before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 5px;
    background: black;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -.75em;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    transform: scale(0, 1);
    transition: transform ease-in-out 250ms;
  }
  nav a:hover::before{
    transform: scale(1,1);
  }
}


.parheader{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  min-height: 20vh;
  padding: 45vw 0 5vw;
  position: relative;
  transform-style: inherit;
  width: 100vw;
}

.parheader, .parheader:before{
  background: 50% 50% / cover;
}

.parheader::before{
  bottom: 0;
  content: "";
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  background-image: url(../kuvat/header.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  transform-origin: center center 0;
  transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2);
  z-index: -1;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

  .parheader * {
    font-weight: normal;
    letter-spacing: 0.2em;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 1em 0;
    height: 1em;
    position: relative
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>W3.CSS Template</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/nav.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>
body,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {font-family: "Lato", sans-serif}
.w3-bar,h1,button {font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif}
.fa-laptop,.fa-bug {font-size:200px}
</style>
<body>
<!-- Navbar -->

<header>
      <div class="navibar">
        <a href="index.php"><img src="kuvat/logo.png" alt="logo" class="logo"></a>
      <input type="checkbox" id="nav-toggle" class="nav-toggle">

      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="index.php">Etusivu</a></li>
          <li><a href="sivut/tehtavat.php">Tehtävät</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Tietoa</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">ota yhteyttä</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Kirjaudu sisään</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <label for="nav-toggle" class="nav-toggle-label">
        <span></span>
      </label>
      </div>

</header>


<!-- Header -->
<header>
    <div class="parheader">
    </div>
    <div class="center">
  <p>KOTISIVU</p>
</div>
</header>


</body>
</html>
```

So i was making navigatorbar nothing too impressive just trying to learn little bit and i came across this weird problem. When i try it on mobile it still shows the panel and text that should be hidden so if any of you guys could help me with this. some screenshots of my problem that im facing:

[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSJbE.png)

[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUfsK.jpg)

Not sure if you can see anything from those photos but that transparent panel and text wont go away for some reason so please help me. don't mind the look of it just testing around and i really want to get it to work. Stackoverflow wants me to type more details for some reason. Hiding other things works fine like that drop down button but that panel wont do it.

Comment: Your panel correctly disappears for me at a mobile width, and you don't appear to have any rules that would be overwriting the `display: none`. Are you sure there's no additional CSS targetting the element? Have you got any JavaScript that could have an effect? Finally, and most likely, it's a caching issue where you have cached outdated stylesheets. Try `CTRL + SHIFT + R` to clear your cache.

Comment: There is no javascript that could affect it, but still not working for me. Having that weird panel and text on it. Its from desktop version thing that says KOTISIVU

Comment: Oh and it wont show me website css on mobile for some reason. it should look something like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSJbE.png

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
 @media screen and (min-width: 600px)
```

To this:

```
 @media screen and (max-width: 600px)
```

**Explanation:**

max-width: 600px //means the media query will occur for screen sizes below 600px in width

min-width: 600px //means the media query will occur for screen sizes above 600px in width

Also understand that media queries can also be dependent on screen height as well. In which case you deal with max-height and min-height